# Python: Get attribute with integer name from object

Tags: python, python-2.7, attributes, integer

I recently discovered I could do this in Python:

```
>>> obj = type("SomeObj", (), {1: "a", 2: "b", 3: "c"})()
>>> obj
<__main__.SomeObj object at 0x123456789>
```

The object `obj` definitely has the attributes `1`, `2` and `3`, as `dir()` shows:

```
>>> dir(obj)
[1, 2, 3, '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', ...]
```

However, I was not able to retrieve the value of one of the three attributes.

```
>>> obj.1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    obj.1
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> getattr(obj, "1")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ObjectifiedDict' object has no attribute '1'

>>> obj.__getattribute__(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: attribute name must be string, not 'int'
```

Is there any way to do this?
I know that using integers as attribute names is generally a **bad** idea, it just made me curious.

Comment: Since it is just for fun and you're hacking anyway, you can access them by using e.g `obj.__dict__[1]`.

Comment: @swenzel, you cannot using the OP's code, `__dict__` would be empty.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I tried it out, for me it works... nvm, forgot to istantiate, but then you can use `obj.__class__.__dict__[1]` :D

Comment: @swenzel, you tried  `obj = type("SomeObj", (), {1: "a", 2: "b", 3: "c"})` not  `obj = type("SomeObj", (), {1: "a", 2: "b", 3: "c"})()`

Comment: I'm reasonably confident that this is invalid code, and that it doesn't throw an error is implementation defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a dict to type which can use ints as keys, there is no check in type to see if you are passing a valid [name](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) so you get a  *SyntaxError* trying to access the attribute later:

> Identifiers (also referred to as names) are described by the following >lexical definitions:
>       identifier ::=  (letter|"*") (letter | digit | "*")*

The attribute must be passed as a string to *hasattr* and *getattr* where an exception is raised ever before a lookup is attempted.

```
PyDoc_STRVAR(hasattr_doc,
"hasattr(object, name) -> bool\n\
\n\
Return whether the object has an attribute with the given name.\n\
(This is done by calling getattr(object, name) and catching exceptions.)");


PyDoc_STRVAR(getattr_doc,
"getattr(object, name[, default]) -> value\n\
\n\
Get a named attribute from an object; getattr(x, 'y') is equivalent to x.y.\n\
When a default argument is given, it is returned when the attribute doesn't\n\
exist; without it, an exception is raised in that case.");



if (!PyString_Check(name)) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,
                    "hasattr(): attribute name must be string");
    return NULL;
}



if (!PyString_Check(name)) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,
                    "getattr(): attribute name must be string");
    return NULL;
}
```

[bltinmodule.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c)

[typeobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c)

*integers as attribute names is generally a bad idea* should be *is impossible* for the reasons listed above.

You would also get a `TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()` using `dir` in python 3 as the attributes get sorted:

```
PyDoc_STRVAR(dir_doc,
"dir([object]) -> list of strings\n"
"\n"
"If called without an argument, return the names in the current scope.\n"
"Else, return an alphabetized list of names comprising (some of) the attributes\n"
"of the given object, and of attributes reachable from it.\n"
"If the object supplies a method named __dir__, it will be used; otherwise\n"
"the default dir() logic is used and returns:\n"
"  for a module object: the module's attributes.\n"
"  for a class object:  its attributes, and recursively the attributes\n"
"    of its bases.\n"
"  for any other object: its attributes, its class's attributes, and\n"
"    recursively the attributes of its class's base classes.");
```

Answer (score 1):

you may access to `1` or `2` or `3` arguments

```
obj = type("SomeObj", (), {1: "a", 2: "b", 3: "c"})()
obj.__class__.__dict__[1]
obj.__class__.__dict__[2]
obj.__class__.__dict__[3]
```

but not sure why it works ..... if anyone can edit my post, explaining it
This works in python 3.4.1 and Python 2.7.6

**EDIT thanks Veedrac**

```
vars(type(obj))[1]
vars(type(obj))[2]
vars(type(obj))[3]
```

**EDIT 2 Only Read**

however these attributes are read only

```
vars(type(obj))[1]="change"  # or obj.__class__.__dict__[1]="change"
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> TypeError: 'dictproxy' object does not support item assignment

```
 setattr(type(obj), 1, "change")
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> TypeError: attribute name must be string, not 'int'

Comment: because the keys exist in the dict, the problem is they are not valid identifiers to use as attribute names

Comment: @PadraicCunningham then `1` , `2`, `3` are attributes of the class, but for it not having valid names can not access these , right? .....

Comment: yes, you cannot have `self.1 = ...`, it is not a valid identifier. There is no check  in type to see if you passed a valid identifier as an instance name so the keys appear in the dict but you will never be able to access using instance.attribute

Comment: @Veedrac you are right `vars` is much better [vars api](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) .... edit my post